# C#/MVC Wrap View with Partial?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to wrap a view with a partial file?  Sort of like a layout, but with a partial?

For example:

Layout

```
<html>
...
<body>
<div>@RenderBody</div>
</body>
</html>
```

View

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PartialWrapper.cshtml";
}

<!--content I want to wrap with partial-->
<div class='alert alert-info'>HELLO WORLD</div>
```

Partial

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div style='border:1px solid #cccccc;'>
    <div style='background-color:black;color:white;'>
         StackOverflow Rocks
    </div>
    <div>
         @RenderBody
    </div>
</div>
```

When I tried the above scenario, I get an error on the partial file on the "@RenderBody" line.  The error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments
```

Is there a better way to do this -- or make the above work?

Comment: RenderBody is a Method @RenderBody()

Comment: doh!  you're right - left off the ().  Can you create an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: is too simple, just upvote my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Overmachine mentioned, RenderBody is a Method so you need to write @RenderBody() like so:

```html
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div style='border:1px solid #cccccc;'>
    <div style='background-color:black;color:white;'>
         StackOverflow Rocks
    </div>
    <div>
         @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```